# Use API to read SQL Server SSIS Package and determine Data Flow Task execution sequence

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520388/how-to-use-ssis-api-to-read-a-package-and-determine-task-sequence-from-code-pre), I figured out how to use the SQL Server API to programmatically determine the order in which SSIS tasks on the "Control Flow" tab are executed by reading the *Precedence Constraints* collection either via the API or reading the raw XML in the dtsx file. Now, I similarly want to programmatically figure out the order in which objects in a "Data Flow Task" run. At this point, I'd be happy just to understand how the XML represents this info.

Unlike the earlier post in which I could see in the XML how the precedence information was stored (in the Precedence Constraint collection) but was just having trouble trying to determine how to use the API to get at the info, for Data Flow task "streams" or "series of connected arrows", I am even confused at how this info is reprsented when I look at the raw DTSX file in notepad or IE.

I suspect that the info that stores the order in which the sequence that the objects within a Data Flow Task are execute is either stored in the PATHS collection. Here's a sample:

```
- <paths>
  <path id="128" name="OLE DB Source Output" description="" startId="42" endId="117" /> 
  <path id="129" name="Data Conversion Output" description="" startId="118" endId="48" /> 
  </paths>
```

..or somehow disguised in the Lineage property, but I can't seem to relate the IDs specified in eiether in a meaningful way to the objects.

**Why don't you try it by following this example and see if you can figure out of this info is represented in the XML?**

Create a simple package with one Data Flow Task:

[image]

Double click on it and then add the following two sample two tasks that execute in a sequence:

[image]

Then open up the DTSX file in Notepad and determine how this sequencing/ordering info is stored in a meaningful way. Serious bonus points if you can tell me how to use the SQL Server API to get at this info.

**Side bar on how to view a dtsx file as xml using IE:**
Note that IE makes a good XML viewer. All I had to do was make a copy of my simple HelloWorld dtsx file, remove the optional xml version node at the top and wrap the remaining xml in a dummy   tag, save the file with an xml extension and drag it to an open IE window...

Comment: Is someone paying you to do this? What's the point?

Comment: Im writing a crawler that parses script files, databases, ssis packages , config files,stored procedures and traces and graphs data flows and makes systems very searchable.

Answer (score 0):

startId maps to the output element with the corresponding id
EndId maps to the input element with the corresponding id

Answer (score 0):

I just traversed through the xml and found that starting and end component names are present here, rt. So just parse the xml an retrieving those values, helps in a clear idea of path. I don't see any id's though.
[Starting and end component names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZDT6.png)